# Jest branch coverage is missing one (in every component)

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

I'm very confused on the concept of branch coverage in jest: I've got this very simple component that I want to get 100% coverage one. However, I can only get up to 3/4 branches, it doesn't make a lot of sense. This happens in every component in our application. What could the missing branch possibly be? All this does is render.

Card.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import '../../../Styles/Layout.css';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Card extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    date: PropTypes.string, // This gets passed in as a string from the API
    slug: PropTypes.string,
    image: PropTypes.string,
    title: PropTypes.string,
    description: PropTypes.string
  };

  render() {
    let date = new Date(this.props.date);
    return (
      <div className="uk-width-1-1 uk-width-1-2@s uk-width-1-3@m uk-margin-bottom">
        <div className="uk-card uk-card-small uk-card-default">
          <div className="uk-card-media-top">
            <Link to={`/blog/${date.getFullYear()}/${date.getMonth()}/${date.getDay()}/${this.props.slug}`}><img id="blog-card-image" src={this.props.image} alt="Calgary" /></Link>
          </div>
          <div className="uk-card-header">
            <div className="uk-grid-small uk-flex-middle" data-uk-grid>
              <div className="uk-width-auto">
                <h3 className="uk-card-title uk-margin-remove-bottom">{this.props.title}</h3>
                <p className="uk-text-meta uk-margin-remove-top">{date.toDateString()}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="uk-card-body">
            <p>{this.props.description}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="uk-card-footer">
            <Link to={`/blog/${date.getFullYear()}/${date.getMonth()}/${date.getDay()}/${this.props.slug}`} className="uk-button uk-button-text">Read more</Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Card;
```

Card.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import Card from '../../../../Components/Core/Cards/Card';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('Card', () => {
  it('renders without crashing', () => {
    const component = shallow(<Card image="/path/to/img" date="2018-02-08 14:21:36" description="Test description of a blog post" slug="test-slug-blog-post" title="Test slug blog post"/>);
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Edit: 
[image: Here is the requested coverage file]

Comment: Do you have the coverage results locally? It should denote which line is not covered.

Comment: Line coverage is 100%.
100% Statements 12/12 75% Branches 3/4 100% Functions 2/2 100% Lines 7/7

Comment: I think @dcodesmith asked about html file, where jest prints your component with comments along with each line. This file is located in automatically created `coverage` directory of your project. It looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ2FN.png. Can you please add screenshot from coverage file, generated for `Card` component, to your question?

Comment: @AndrewMiroshnichenko, yes, that. Thanks for clarifying